# Yogurt, overcoked

Tags: food-science, yogurt

I have a yogurt maker - I heat the milk, add the starter and plug it in. Easy peasy! After 7 - 9 hours, I (usually) unplug the maker and put the yogurt in the refrigerator overnight and it's ready to eat in the morning. Last night I forgot to put it in the fridge and I JUST did it so the yogurt incubated 17 hours. What happened to it? Will it be OK to eat?!

Answer (score 3):

It will be fine.  It may be a bit more sour tasting than usual, but it will not be unsafe.

Comment: It turned out great.